# How to pass install referrer string to my App

Tags: android, install-referrer

I've implemented the install referrer mechanism in my app and I weel receive it in `InstallReferrerReceiver::onReceive()` like that:

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "InstallReferrerReceiver: " + referrer);

        // And then how to pass referrer to my App?
    }
}
```

According to what I see, it's called just after the installation done but the app is not yet started as it will be done once I'll click on `open` in the GooglePlay appstore.

So how can I pass the referrer string to my app to process it?

I tried to store it in `defaultSharedPreferences` but I cannot read it once the application is running.

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "Version code: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);

        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "InstallReferrerReceiver: " + referrer);

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "Store referrer in " + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context.getApplicationContext()));
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Constants.REFERRAL, referrer).apply();
        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "Stored referrer is " + sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.REFERRAL, null));
    }
}
```

But it seems `getDefaultSharedPreferences` refers to a restricted context in `InstallReferrerReceiver`, different from the one used in the application.

So how do solve this problem?
I just precise I use it for private parameters, it's not regarding any Campaign!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to store data in SharedPrefs using:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
 preferencesEditor.putString(Constants.REFERRAL, referrer);
 preferencesEditor.commit();
```